# Socket error on server only

Tags: java, sockets, networking, jdbc

Have a java program which is trying to insert about 150k records to sql server database and failing with the error below on production server .

> [Microsoft][SQLServer 2000 Driver for JDBC]Error establishing socket

Started seeing these errors after the increase in data volume i.e the number of inserts. The SQL Server connection works fine.

I tried changing the JDBC string by setting Max connection pool as below

```
String DB_URL= "jdbc:sqlserver://example.com:11111;SelectMethod=Direct;DatabaseName=DB1;Max Pool Size=100000"
```

On local machine the program works fine. This tells the nothing wrong with program.

Only when trying to run the same program on prod server is the issue. Even on server seeing this error only after the data volume increase. Prior to that even on server the program was working fine.

Is socket error mostly network issue?? Need help with the same please.

Here is the stacktrace

```
java.sql.SQLException: [Microsoft][SQLServer 2000 Driver for JDBC]Error establishing socket.
at com.microsoft.jdbc.base.BaseExceptions.createException(Unknown Source)
at com.microsoft.jdbc.base.BaseExceptions.getException(Unknown Source)
at com.microsoft.jdbc.base.BaseExceptions.getException(Unknown Source)
at com.microsoft.jdbc.sqlserver.tds.TDSConnection.<init>(Unknown Source)
at com.microsoft.jdbc.sqlserver.SQLServerImplConnection.open(Unknown Source)
at com.microsoft.jdbc.base.BaseConnection.getNewImplConnection(Unknown Source)
at com.microsoft.jdbc.base.BaseConnection.getImplConnection(Unknown Source)
at com.microsoft.jdbc.base.BaseStatement.setupImplConnection(Unknown Source)
at com.microsoft.jdbc.base.BaseStatement.<init>(Unknown Source)
at com.microsoft.jdbc.base.BasePreparedStatement.<init>(Unknown Source)
at com.microsoft.jdbc.base.BaseConnection.prepareStatement(Unknown Source)
at com.microsoft.jdbc.base.BaseConnection.prepareStatement(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: There was a stack trace. Post it. In your question.

Comment: [Microsoft][SQLServer 2000 Driver for JDBC]Error establishing socket.
I see.

Comment: That's an error message. I asked for the stack trace.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The incoming tabular data stream (TDS) remote procedure call (RPC) protocol stream is incorrect. Parameter 1 (""): Data type 0x38 is unknown](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39538674/the-incoming-tabular-data-stream-tds-remote-procedure-call-rpc-protocol-stre)

Comment: @GordThompson I cannot see any connection other than the presence of SQLServer in both. The error message here is different. Your duplicate at least has a connection. This one doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

This kind of error could happen if you are running out of DB server connection (there are limits to concurrent connection in the DB servers, refer server doc) dues to connection leak. You have not put up your code, so it is difficult to tell, however, it is worthwhile to check the following:

1) Are you per chance inserting only one record per connection and getting a new connection to insert the next record?
2) Are you closing the connection after inserting the record/(s)?

If possible, batch your inserts with a PreparedStatement and addBatch and see it that makes any difference.

Comment: Thanks, for trying to help me. I am doing batch inserts and closing connection too. Finally figured out what the issue was and resolved this issue. The program was loading sql server 2000 and 2008 drivers. I downloaded the new sql server driver and used only that. After that the program is running fine. Thanks, again for all your help.