# The incoming tabular data stream (TDS) remote procedure call (RPC) protocol stream is incorrect. Parameter 1 (""): Data type 0x38 is unknown

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc

Trying to connect to sqlserver DB and retrieve info and later insert to it.
On the server getting this error when trying to make a JDBC call with select.

```
java.sql.SQLException: [Microsoft][SQLServer 2000 Driver for JDBC][SQLServer]The incoming tabular data stream (TDS) remote procedure call (RPC) protocol stream is incorrect. Parameter 1 (""): Data type 0x38 is unknown.
at com.microsoft.jdbc.base.BaseExceptions.createException(Unknown Source)
at com.microsoft.jdbc.base.BaseExceptions.getException(Unknown Source)
at com.microsoft.jdbc.sqlserver.tds.TDSRequest.processErrorToken(Unknown Source)
at com.microsoft.jdbc.sqlserver.tds.TDSRequest.processReplyToken(Unknown Source)
at com.microsoft.jdbc.sqlserver.tds.TDSRPCRequest.processReplyToken(Unknown Source)
at com.microsoft.jdbc.sqlserver.tds.TDSRequest.processReply(Unknown Source)
at com.microsoft.jdbc.sqlserver.tds.TDSCursorRequest.openCursor(Unknown Source)
at com.microsoft.jdbc.sqlserver.SQLServerImplStatement.execute(Unknown Source)
at com.microsoft.jdbc.base.BaseStatement.commonExecute(Unknown Source)
at com.microsoft.jdbc.base.BaseStatement.executeQueryInternal(Unknown Source)
at com.microsoft.jdbc.base.BasePreparedStatement.executeQuery(Unknown Source)
```

On my local machine everything is working fine. Not sure what needs to be done. Please need help on this.

The classpath on server contains path to the below jars in this order.

```
msutil.jar
mssqlserver.jar
msbase.jar
sqljdbc4.jar
```

Comment: are you certain that the local and remote data models are 100% equivalent?

Comment: Also compare versions of SQL Server on the local and remote machines. If you really are using "SQLServer 2000 Driver for JDBC" it may be too old for the job.

Comment: Further to my previous comment, the "Details" section of [this page](https://www.microsoft.com/en-ca/download/details.aspx?id=1511) says "The driver version i.e. SQL Server 2000 JDBC driver, that you are looking for is no longer available for download (please note that the support for the this driver will officially end on July 9, 2010)." In other words, that version of the driver has not been supported in over six (6) years.

Comment: Very true @GordThompson, just being curious! If we replace that with `sqljdbc4.jar`, would it work?

Comment: @N00bPr0grammer re: *"If we replace that with sqljdbc4.jar, would it work?"* - The best way to know the answer to that question is to try it yourself.

Answer (score 2):

You have multiple Microsoft JDBC drivers on your classpath, and as a result you are connecting with the **ancient** MS SQL Server 2000 JDBC driver. Remove the old ones (ie `msutil.jar`, `mssqlserver.jar` and `msbase.jar`), and only leave `sqljdbc4.jar`. Also check if there is a newer version available than the one you are currently using.

Comment: Just having the sqljdbc.jar helped me resolve this issue. Thank you so much.